# laravel 5.4 Form doesn't show anything on localhost. and it also shows no any error message. It's blank

Tags: forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

**Description:**

I downloaded and installed Form from https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html and configure all files as per instructions.

```
  Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

**Problem:**

My Route http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/create is showing a blank page. In actual it should show me a Form. 
There is no any error message in all code or localhost.

**HTML CODE:**

```
@extends('admin.layout.admin')

@section('content')

    <h3>Add Product</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'product.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true, 'data-parsley-validate'=>'']) !!}

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
                {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control','required'=>'','minlength'=>'5')) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('description', 'Description') }}
                {{ Form::text('description', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('price', 'Price') }}
                {{ Form::text('price', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('size', 'Size') }}
                {{ Form::select('size', [ 'small' => 'Small', 'medium' => 'Medium','large'=>'Large'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categories') }}
                {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Select Category']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('image', 'Image') }}
                {{ Form::file('image',array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
            </div>

             {{ Form::submit('Create', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>



@endsection
```

**product.php code**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['name','description','size','category_id','image','price'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductReview::class);
    }

    public function getStarRating()
    {
        $count = $this->reviews()->count();
        if(empty($count)){
            return 0;
        }
        $starCountSum=$this->reviews()->sum('rating');
        $average=$starCountSum/ $count;

       return $average;

    }

}
```

**ProductsController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your routes and controller?

Comment: Route::resource('product','ProductsController');

Comment: Check your controller method `create()` in `ProductsController`, Put `dd('test')` in method and what result you get.

Comment: I have edited my question, Controller code is given please check it, i am unable to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `create()` is empty,so it will not show anything. It should be like this

```
 public function create()
 {
   return view('form');
 }
```

`form` is name on your view.